# CSS Media Queries not working and I've tried everything

Tags: css, media-queries

I would like to include simple media queries to my css file, but they are not working and I've been digging for answers from other questions for too long.

This is the media query I am trying, which I think is most correct:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

I have also tried these versions of the code above:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

This is my html header with the famous meta tag:

```
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tinos&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bdcb973a27.js"></script>
```

This is my footer:

```
  <footer class= "accent-color">
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </footer>
```

I feel like I am going insane with this, please help! Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have the same scripts in your header and footer? What do expect to happen with your media query and styles within it?

Comment: sorry! i need to edit that part of my question. thanks!

Comment: What does dev tools tell that's happening on the `body` tag? Is there another color overriding it? Your first media query works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/6w1n4s0g/ Resize the result window and you'll see once you get less than 600px wide, the background changes to red.

Comment: Do you actually have the <body> defined?  Full code is important for context./

Comment: This is not your issue (or least it shouldn't be) but order of your css files matter. Move your styles.css to after the other css files. Browser it is going to pick those up in order so if you have the same element defined in all (excluding if you are using !important) then the last file to have that element will override the properties defined in the previous css files if they are the same property. You want your specific defined styles to override any bootrapped files. Final css that overrides in inline styles. Just friendly FYI

Comment: @bpeterson76 <body> is not defined.

Comment: @Travis-Action, this actually worked! I suspected it had something to do with bootstrap. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Max-width media queries mean the style will only show up to the width you define. Any of the media queries you've written should work if your screen is 600px or less. Change max-width to min-width and your red background will display on any screen *larger* than 600px wide.

*Assuming your HTML has a body tag and your CSS file is in the location you've referenced.